# Docker Alpine - GraphViz - gvpr causes Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: segmentation-fault, graphviz, alpine-linux

I'm using the docker image `node:12-alpine` and install graphviz using `apk add graphviz`, which installs the version `graphviz-2.42.3-r0`.

But as I try to execute `gvpr`, I get just a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` as you can see in https://gitlab.com/Lepardo/simplewebspider-nodejs/-/jobs/612093260

Any idea, how I can tackle this issue?

Comment: Naively, I'd guess you were missing a library.  But which one?   cheap thrills:  dot -V; dot -v; gvpr -V

Answer (score 1):

The segfault seems to be a bug in the `gvpr` program.

This bug seems to be fixed on the latest gvpr version from the edge repository, [2.47.0-r2](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/graphviz), which could be installed with:

```
 apk add graphviz --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```

On graphviz 2.44.0 (Alpine 3.13 and 3.12), the bug seems to reproduce still.

In the [graphviz gitlab](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/) repository, going over the [commit history](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/commits/main/lib/gvpr/gvpr.c) of `gvpr.c`, this [commit](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/commit/fcf3055a6737dfe3bab7d71d8a6ffd8f17a161af) from 13 Aug 2020 stands out:

> **fix: pass format parameter into gverrorf explicitly**
>
> *Matthew Fernandez authored 8 months ago*
>
> The gverrorf function was prototyped in a way that did not align with a function
> pointer it was stored into. On platforms with more forgiving varargs calling
> conventions, everything worked out OK. However, on other platforms calling
> gverrorf through this function pointer would result in stack corruption. This
> change aligns gverrorf with the type of the function pointer in which it is
> stored.

This potential stack corruption might very well explain the segfault on Alpine, that is based on musl-libc which is generally a more strict libc implementation.
Looking at other commits as well, this seems like the most likely fix.